# what does $a=[$a] mean in PHP?

Tags: php

Seen in functions where `$a` is a function parameter:

```
if(!is_array($a))
    $a=[$a]
```

I just don't know what this means,

Thanks!

Comment: $a will be an array have one element [0] => $a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means;

> *if* `$a` *is not an array, then create* `$a` *as an `array` and use the contents (value) of* `$a` *as the first element of the newly created array called  $a.*

In readable English emulating a Code, this could mean:

```
<?php
    if($a IS NOT AN ARRAY):
        THEN CREATE A NEW VARIABLE $a OF TYPE: ARRAY.
        TAKE WHATEVER IS INSIDE THE INITIAL $a VARIABLE...
        AND PUT IT AS THE FIRST ELEMENT OF THE OVERRIDDEN, NEW $a VARIABLE.
    endif;
```

Answer (score 2):

This code convert $a from some **non-array data-type** to **array data-type**

```
if(!is_array($a))   \\check whether $a is not an array
    $a=[$a]         \\change $a to an array with only one element which was previously stored in $a
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes a simple variable and turns it into an array.

`[$a]` is shorthand for `array($a)`.

If `$a` is not an array, `[$a]` turns it into an array.

Comment: Ok that's cool. Where on god's sake is that on any manual?